# How make i18n for vuetify

Tags: vuejs2, internationalization, vuetify.js

In my vue.js 2.5.7 / vuetify": "^1.0.8" application I  read i18n support
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/internationalization#vue-i18n

and adding lines in my resources/assets/js/app.js :

```
import en from 'vuetify/src/locale/en' // English
import es from 'vuetify/src/locale/es' // Has no Spain files
import uk from 'vuetify/src/locale/uk' // Ukrainian
Vue.use( Vuetify, {
    lang: {
        locales: {en, es, uk},
        current: 'en'
    }
});
```

and got error in my console :

```
ERROR in ./resources/assets/js/app.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vuetify/src/locale/en' in '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/ArtistsRating/resources/assets/js'
```

1) Looks like I need to upload some i18n files to my project, but I did not find from where and into which subdir?

2) There si no spain support? It was not in listing in ref above...

Thanks!

Comment: I think that [this](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/internationalization#create-translation) is more relevant for your case. You need to create a file `es.ts` somewhere in your project and then import it like `import es from './i18n/vuetify/es'`. Actually I'm moving this to an answer.

Comment: It seems no `es` thus far https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/dev/src/locale

Comment: @Ivan Hi, does it works for you? Because when I follow the documentation, as Ale pointed out in his answer, and do {{ $vuetify.t('my-component.text') }} I don’t get the translated text. How do you display the translated text in your component? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/internationalization#getting-started)

Create a folder in your project like `projectName//i18n/vuetify/` and there create a file that with name `es.ts`. It should look something like this:

```
export default {
  "dataIterator": {
    "rowsPerPageText": "Items per page:",
    "rowsPerPageAll": "All",
    "pageText": "{0}-{1} of {2}",
    "noResultsText": "No matching records found",
    "nextPage": "Next page",
    "prevPage": "Previous page"
  },
  "dataTable": {
    "rowsPerPageText": "Rows per page:"
  },
  "noDataText": "No data available"
}
```

Then in your main js file `app.js` you should have:

```
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'

// Your own translation file
import es from './i18n/vuetify/es'

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  lang: {
    locales: { es },
    current: 'es'
  }
})
```

I haven't tested this but hope it will work.

Answer (score 2):

You need only to change `vuetify/src/locale/en` by `vuetify/lib/locale/en` and it should works without the need to create any additional file (spain in now supported by vuertify)